# The question about transformation...

Tags: self-learning, transformation

The problem is $f(x)=1/3$
the range of $X$ is $(-1,2)$
zero elsewhere
find the pdf of $Y=X^2$.

I tried using the pdf of $Y$ using transformation formula (not cumulative method)

and about the setting range... 
jacobian part $X=+-\sqrt {y}$ so divided it to part when for $-1< x<0$ and $0< x<2$
but when it becomes about $y$, there are $2$ overlapped range part for
$-1< x<0,0< x<1$  both becomes $ 0< y<1$,

so i calculate is for when $-1< x<0$ and

multiple $2$ for the $0< x<1$ part... is it correct logic?

and i continued to finish the question the answer becomes
$1/3\sqrt {y }, 0< y<1$ and 
$1/6\sqrt {y} ,1< y<4$ and
$0$          elsewhere.

Is it correct?

and one more... how can i solve this with a cdf method?

Comment: Is your answer the pdf or cdf?  You could try $F_Y (y)=Pr(X^2\leq y)=\dots$ and differentiate this.

Comment: my answer is about the pdf by using transformation formula...

Comment: i tried to do with a cdf method but range problem caught me...

Comment: Again you may have to distinguish between the two branches. I am getting $\sqrt {y}^{-1} $ where you get $\sqrt {y}$ either using the theorem that uses the 'inverse' or differentiating the cdf.@user154797

Comment: i think then we have same value.. i wrote √y in the denominator part... 1 over 3√y ...so is it same with you??

Comment: I see. Then we got the same result.#user154797